# No sound through TV over HDMI

Tags: 12.10, sound, hdmi

My issue is that I can't get the sound in my TV which I connected via HDMI.
I used ubuntu 12.10 and ATI HD6770.
I'm totally new in ubuntu.
Who can help me?

Comment: Not familiar with HDMI, but it might help if you added logs mate. try /var/log/syslog and /var/log/dmesg, perhaps this is for you: http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/04/14/audio-over-hdmi-and-displayport-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 2):

First check to make sure there is an HDMI output listed and selected under Sound Settings.
[image]

If you don't see one, you'll need to install the proprietary drivers for your graphics card with the instructions found in [this answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/129200/15939) Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard and copy and paste the commands in line by line.

Comment: Hi, When I install the driver. An error raise. And here is the detail in log file:Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.

Comment: @user127945 It looks like you missed installing the dependencies from the answer above that one. You need to run 
`sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases` and
`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`. If you're using the 64bit version of ubuntu you also need to run `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch i386`lib32gcc1 libc6-i386` and then try the instructions in the answer I linked again.